# In postgres, how do I divide values of an odd index with with values of an even index?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table

```
ind | val
----+----
1   | 0.11
2   | 0.12
3   | 0.13
4   | 0.14
5   | 0.15
6   | 0.16
```

I would like to divide the even elements by the odd elements. So I want to return something like

```
ind2 | val2
----+----
1   | 0.12/0.11
2   | 0.14/0.13
3   | 0.16/0.15
```

What SQL query can I run to output the desired format?

Thank you for any help.

---

More about my situation.
I really start off with a table of arrays. For a selected row, I want to take the array and divide the even elements of the array by the odd elements of the array.

When I wanted to sum the odd and even elements together, I did something like

```
SELECT
  "timestamp" AS "time",
  ((ind-1)-(ind-1)%2)/2 AS frequency,
  20*LOG(SQRT(SUM(val*val))) as vna_data
FROM 
v_recent_vna_reflection,
UNNEST(value_cal) WITH ORDINALITY a(val,ind)
WHERE
  id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM v_recent_vna_reflection)
GROUP BY timestamp, frequency
```

But division isn't an aggregate function that would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation for the question you are asking about rows.  You might want to ask another question about arrays.

```
select ceiling(id / 2.0) as id,
       max(val) filter (where id % 2 = 0) / max(val) filter (where id % 2 = 1) as ratio
from t
group by ceiling(id / 2.0);
```